# Forcing Youtube app to choose low resolution on videos

Tags: wi-fi, youtube

I'm going to let my kids stream Youtube from a mobile wireless hotspot on a tablet via the Youtube app.

The issue is Youtube will select Full HD resolution when it can. My kids will not change resolution for every video they will watch.

How can I force Youtube to pick low resolution video by default, when on Wifi?

Comment: You could check in the network settings to define your hotspot as "mobile data" (on the tablet): *Settings › Wireless & Networks › Datausage*, tap the "3-dots" button (aka "overflow menu"), select *Mobile Hotspots* and check your mobile hotspot name. See if that helps, and please report back.

Comment: In addition to what @Izzy said, you will also have to go to the Settings menu on your YouTube app, and under general, turn on "Limit mobile data usage".

Comment: thanks guys. Initially i did what Izzy said, but the video size was 720 both times. it is something to look further in to though, like do i need to reboot the wifi or something? 

I could see "limit mobile data usage", but will look further. thanks again!!!

Comment: further to this:

network restrictions: "Here you can set a Wi-Fi as metered, so it will restrict background data and provide you warnings for large downloads"

guess it is not what i want.

Comment: Still no resolution to this. It is ridiculous that the Youtube app has no way to set resolution preferences *in general*. WiFi is not always free and unlimited.